# How to initialize a file system?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, partitioning

I have some partitions on /dev/sda. I want to remove them all of them programatically. One way is to list all partitions and then delete them one by one. Another way is to just execute

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

The first option failed when I got some problem with my partition table due to which the listing of the current partitions was not giving any output thereby I was unable to delete any current partition.

The second method is taking too long. Is there any "quick way" to just set the whole hard disk (/dev/sda) as unpartitioned from a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1k count=100`

Try that. Should kill the partition table in no time.

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed. bs is Bus size, i guess. What does count do?

Comment: bs is block size in bytes, so it's writing 100k to the beginning of the device.

Answer (score 1):

[`mkfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs)`/dev/sda`

Be aware that not everything likes to have a whole disk like this.

Answer (score 0):

If [`parted`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/index.shtml) is on your system, you could interact with that and issue commands to delete partitions—and list them too for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the existing partitions, consider just creating the new ones. Unless you want to ensure that your machine won't boot off the hard drive (for example, to force a netboot on the next startup) in which case the "dd" recipe is fine.

You don't need 100k, 512 bytes will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to do this is to use `sfdisk` with empty input:

```
echo | /sbin/sfdisk /dev/sda
```